# Python Pong Game Using Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, python-2.x

I have been making this pong game, but I can't figure out how to make the hits not register to the bat when it underneath it. Can someone help me fix it?

Also, if you move the bat back and forth you basically will hit every shot.

So can someone please help me fix both of those problems?

Code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import pygame.freetype

circle_x= 250
circle_y= 250

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

mp3=pygame.mixer.music.load("nana.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()

font = pygame.freetype.Font("msyh.ttc")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("game")

move_x = 2
move_y = 2

score = 0
deaths = 0
level = 1

minus1 = -1
minus2 = -1
plus1 = 1
plus2 = 1
minus3 = -1

while True:

    if score >= 50:
        level = 2
        minus1 = -2
        minus2 = -2
        plus1 = 2
        plus2 = 2
        minus3 = -2

    mouse_x,mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,(100,100,100),(circle_x,circle_y),20)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(mouse_x,500,100,10))

    circle_x = circle_x+move_x
    circle_y = circle_y+move_y
    
    font_image,font_rect = font.render('Score: '+str(score),fgcolor=(0,0,0),size=30)
    font_image1,font_rect1 = font.render('Deaths: '+str(deaths),fgcolor=(0,0,0),size=30)
    font_image2,font_rect2 = font.render('Level: '+str(level),fgcolor=(0,0,0),size=30)
    screen.blit(font_image,(20,10))
    screen.blit(font_image1,(600,10))
    screen.blit(font_image2,(300,10))
    
    if circle_x>800:
        move_x = minus1
    if circle_y>600:
        score = 0
        deaths += 1
        move_y = -50
    if circle_y<0:
        move_y= plus1
    if circle_x<0:
        move_x = plus2      

    if circle_y >= 500 and mouse_x <= circle_x <= mouse_x+100:
        if move_y > 0:
            score += 5
        move_y = -1
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
            pygame.quit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you isolate the problem, please? Read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually super esy, barely an inconvenience. See this part of your code:

```
    if circle_y >= 500 and mouse_x <= circle_x <= mouse_x+100:
        if move_y > 0:
            score += 5
        move_y = -1
```

You make the ball bounce if the ball's `y` coordinate is at or past the pedal's `y` coordinates.

Instead, only make it bounce if the ball's `y` coordinate is at the pedal's `y` coordinate, including the width of the pedal.

Your pedal is `10` pixels wide, so add another condition `500 + 10 >= circle_y`:

```
    if 510 >= circle_y >= 500 and mouse_x <= circle_x <= mouse_x+100:
        if move_y > 0:
            score += 5
        move_y = -1
```